# Symfony2/Doctrine2 : A way to save (flush) data even if some represent an issue?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a few Excel files that I import to a MySQL database. The Excel files are big, and so is the database. The thing is when my script persists many objects, there must be something wrong with some. Therefore, I need a way to flush and store the data even if there was a problem with some.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: install `gnumeric`, convert xls(x) to csv, parse liny by line and add to database.

Comment: I already do that.. It's no big deal.. That's not what I'm asking for.. I have no problem related to Excel. I have a problem when it comes to Doctrine2. Is there a possibility that the objects I persisted be flushed even though there are -for instance- some duplicates ?

Answer (score 0):

Helping ensure data integrity is partly what Doctrine is for. If you're having issues with duplicates and you don't mind them being in the database then you should be able to permit duplicates in your Doctrine schema.

I'd be inclined to bypass Doctrine and import the data directly into the database. Some of those issues you can probably get end users to fix the first time they try to save the entity.